# SQL Server getdate() format

Tags: sql-server

How to get format like `19 Dec 2012` from getdate() function in tsql

```
select convert(varchar(11),getdate(),?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select convert(varchar(11),getdate(),106)`

Answer (score 1):

[Cast and Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) lists the available formats:

```
106     dd mon yy
```

looks about right.

I'd generally avoid doing any formatting on the database. Keep dates as dates as long as possible - only convert at the last moment in displaying it to the user (similarly, for any input, prefer to convert it from string into its proper data type as early as possible)

Answer (score 1):

```
 -- Can use if SQL 2008 and above (precision to nanoseconds)
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), SYSDATETIME(), 106)

 -- otherwise (precision to miliseconds)
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 106)
```